# Ожидание localhost

Tags: javascript, express, pug

Вечер добрый, работаю на `Express` имеется init для запуска:

```
const express = require("express");
const server = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

server.use(cookieParser());
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const routes = require("./routes");

server.use('/src', express.static('src'));
server.use('/styles', express.static('styles'));
server.set("view engine", "pug");
server.use("/", routes);
server.listen(3000, ()=>{ // Запуск
    console.log("Server started at http://localhost:3000")
});
```

Файл обработки запросов routes:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
let lib = require("./lib");
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = router;

function responseOK(){
    return {
        "ok": true,
        "message": ""
    }
}

router.get("/", (req, res, next)=>{
    res.render("main", {lib})
    next()
})

router.get('/book/:num([0-9]+):home(y||)', (req, res, next)=>{
    if( req.params.num in lib ){
        if( req.params.home === '' ){
            res.render("main", {lib})
            console.log("render")
        }
        else
            res.json(responseOK())
    }
    console.log("render is over")
    next()
})


router.get('*', (req, res)=>{
    res.status(404);
    console.log("404")
});
```

При обращении в корень `/` страница загружается нормально, при обращении к `/book/:num([0-9]+):home(y||)` при пустом параметре home, страница бесконечно грузится с надписью ожидание localhost. В чём может быть причина?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по всему, запрос попадает в обработчик 404, а `res.status(404)` устанавливает заголовок, но не посылает ответ. Замените на `res.sendStatus(404)`

Comment: @НикитаУмнов `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` ошибка такого рода возникает

Comment: Вы именно заменили `res.status(404)` или рядом добавили? Ошибка говорит, что ответ уже был отправлен. Чтобы не путаться, рекомендую везде, где вы отправляете ответ клиенту и логика заканчивается, добавлять return. Например `return res.render("main")`

Comment: @НикитаУмнов, заменил, снифер показал, что он не может загрузить статические файлы, картинка в посте

Comment: В url статики добавьте слеш в начале `href="/styles/main.css"` чтобы путь от корня сайта был

Comment: @НикитаУмнов статики прописаны в init'e, а в пуге, используются эти относительные директории. Кстати если так сделать, то ложится загрузка даже при обращении в корень

Comment: Вы в pug изменили путь, или где? Не может из-за этого ничего сломаться на backend

Comment: @НикитаУмнов вы правы, неправильно использовал статики в пуге, спасибо